# How to achieve human-readable mitmdump output file without internet/python/pip/etc.?

Tags: python, json, format, mitmproxy, har

I've seen various old/gone ideas -- like the '-dd' switch -- and i've seen myriad contrib options, all of which seem to require python, and pip, and internet, and a whole bunch of things that I just don't have in my current environment.

it the output format of mitmdump new to mitmdump?

is there any other tool that just dumps output in a human-readable format without having to install mitmproxy or other python modules/libs?

i can write some code, so i guess i can look at the existing code and just write my own stuff. i do have python and java and etc -- i just can't add anything to what is on my machine, except for the stuff i can copy/paste from the few web pages I have access to.

thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you are trying to achieve. Does `--set flow_detail=3` do what you want?

Comment: If you don't have Internet on your PC you have to develop everything on your own. For Stackoverflow this question is a bit too broad as developing a sniffer/proxy without external dependencies requires thousands of line of code.

Comment: the "--set flow-detail=3" gets "human-readable-ish", but i'm looking for "human-redable-by-a-human"

i.e. formatted output like we would see in curl, mitmweb, a browser/addon, telnet, etc. -- headers, each on a newline, etc.

...if this output format is new, maybe someone wrote a new reader class for it?